# React - exports from root app.js file not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

If my project looks like this:

`/app.js <--- specified as the application entry point in webpack.config.js
 /test.js
 /components/aComponent.js`

and `app.js` contains this:

`export const aString = "hello";
 require('./components/aComponent.js');`

and `test.js` contains this:

`export const bString = "wassup";`

and `/components/aComponent.js` contains this:

`import { aString } from '../app';
 import { bString } from '../test';
 console.log("a string: " + aString);
 console.log("b string: " + bString);`

The output will be:

`a string: undefined
 b string: 'wassup'`

So any file, whether in a subdirectory or adjacent to app.js, can not access the exports. There is no compile errors from webpack as per usual if I make a typo in the filename of an import, the exports just always return undefined.

All of the other components, actions, reducers, selectors, and utils in my project are exporting / importing as expected, and I have tried both './../app' and '../app' in the path but once again, there are no compile errors so I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with cyclic dependencies. This is definitely not a good practice and you should move your constants out of `app.js` if possible. `app.js` imports `./components/aComponent.js` which imports `test.js` which imports `app.js` which imports `./components/aComponent.js`... I'm not 100% sure as to whether or not that's the reason, but ideally your entry point should import all dependencies required for your bundle, and no js files should depend on it. Move the constants to a `constants.js` file or something and import it wherever the constants are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jake Miller - I did manage to discover a circular dependency in my code. I was able to move the consts out of my app.js file and resolve the issue. thanks.